# Why my function dont send variables in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a code in php that generates a button and has a java script function in another file, but it does not work, I should send the value $ id to update the database php file, but it does not do anything

index code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="antenderOrden($folio)">Atender</button>
```

javascript code:

```
  function atenderOrden(folio) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '../panel/data.php',
      data: 'folio=' + folio + 'status=A',
      success: function (data) {
          location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
```

php code:

```
//Actualiza el estatus de un registro de orden en la base de datos
if (isset($_POST['folio']) && isset($_POST['status'])) {
    $obj = new Orden();
    $resp = $obj->updateOrden($_POST['folio'], $_POST['status']);
    echo $resp;
    }
    class Orden{
    public function updateOrden($folio, $status) {
        //$conn = new Conexion();
        $conn->conectar();
        $query = "UPDATE c_ordenes SET statuso = '$status' WHERE folio = '$folio'";
        try {
            $resp = $conn->consulta($query);
            $resp = "OK";
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $resp = $ex;
        }
        $conn->cerrar();
        return $resp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this looks OK. `onclick="antenderOrden($folio)"` is that a PHP variable? Shouldn't it be wrapped in `''`?

Comment: yeah is php variable deafult is 1, and in my database in the table of orders the number 1 is demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `&` to join the last key => value

```
data: 'folio=' + folio + '&status=A',
```

As per my comment, the variable passed in `onclick` should be wrapped in quotes otherwise, javascript sees it as a javascript variable and returns an undefined variable error in console.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="antenderOrden('<?php echo $folio; ?>')">Atender</button>
```

Also you should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks

[Quick Start to using prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: necessary? if it is already within a php function.

echo "<button type = \" button \ "class = \" btn btn-primary \ "onclick = \" antenderOrder ($ folio) \ "> Attending </ button>"

add & in javascript but it does not work yet

Answer (score 0):

you need to send it as object to ajax:

```
...
data: {'folio': folio,'status':'A'},
...
```

and update your button to echo the php variable into html.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="antenderOrden('<?=$folio;?>')">Atender</button>
```

Comment: it does not work, the php file does not receive anything and does not update

Comment: also ur button should be: `onclick="antenderOrden('<?=$folio?>')"`

Answer (score 0):

javascript code

```
function atenderOrden(folio) {
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '../panel/data.php',
  data: {
         folio : folio ,
          status : 'A'
        },
  success: function (data) 
  {
      location.reload();
  }
});
}
```

index code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="antenderOrden(<?php echo $folio;?>)">Atender</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
For GET method :

```
...
data: {'folio': folio,'status':'A'},
...
```

For POST method :

```
...
data: jQuery.param({'folio': folio,'status':'A'},
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which are written wrong.

1) You have to add php tag `<?php ?>` when you call php variable in html side.

Thats why you have to written like this in html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="antenderOrden(<?php echo $folio;?>)">Atender</button>
```

2) Second method to pass data in ajax is wrong.

There are two types to pass data:

Using & operator and second is data pass in `{}`.

```
data: {
         folio : folio ,
          status : 'A'
        },
```

or

```
data: 'folio=' + folio + '&status=A',
```

Please check and update your code.